# Preexisting login to change to logout link in sub menu

Tags: login, logout

I am using twenty twelve with a child theme. I have a link in my primary nav menu where I have an link for “My Account” which has a sub menu with a “Login/Register” link that redirects to a modified wp-login.php. Is it possible for me to turn the “Login/Register” link into a “Logout” link when a user is logged in? If it is possible, would you know how I could accomplish this, or point me in the right direction?

Everything I've found online is adding a login/logout link to the primary menu.  I would like to leave the menu intact since the "My Account" sub menu will have more links added to it.

I'm not sure if this is relevant but, I created the sub menu using Wordpress menus and created a custom link to redirect it to wp-login.php

Thank you

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I managed to set it up for one client. The code (which should go into the theme's `functions.php`) assumes there's an existing menu item titled 'Login'. Works fine but may not be the best way, so critique is welcome.

```
function wpse0520_modify_login_menu_item( $item ) {

    if(isset($item->title)){
        if( $item->title =='Login' ) {
            if(is_user_logged_in()){
                $item->url = wp_logout_url( get_permalink() );
                $item->title = 'Logout';
            } else {
                $item->url = site_url( 'login' );
            }
        } elseif ( $item->title =='Logout' ) {
            if(!is_user_logged_in()){
                $item->url = site_url( 'login' );
                $item->title = 'Login';
            } else {
                $item->url = wp_logout_url( get_permalink() );
            }
        }
    }
    return $item;
}
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'wpse0520_modify_login_menu_item' );
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution - just plug in an go.